# how could i solve error of modulenotfound? i already installed pandas then still can get error

Tags: python, pandas

I already installed pandas then still got the error of modulenotfound error. so what to do now?

I wanted to run my program but got the error.

Comment: how did you install the library? maybe you have multiple python interpreters. or you're using another python environment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the module in the correct folder and that the python interpreter has access to that folder.Perhaps you are using a virtual environment that does not have access to modules that are installed globally or you are using a virtual environment as the python interpreter for that code.

Comment: now what to do?? could you please explain me? by the way, thanks for the answer

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/module-not-found-error-in-python-solved/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwi61qfO9MH8AhX5TaQEHcY3DtQQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1yWLFTzNxATNma3c_VZxaF...Read that